# Haskell compile time function calculation

Tags: compiler-construction, haskell, static, code-generation, metaprogramming

I would like to precalculate values for a function at compile-time.

Example (real function is more complex, didn't try compiling):

```
base = 10
mymodulus n = n `mod` base -- or substitute with a function that takes
                            -- too much to compute at runtime
printmodules 0 = [mymodulus 0]
printmodules z = (mymodulus z):(printmodules (z-1))

main = printmodules 64
```

I **know** that `mymodulus n` will be called only with `n < 64` and I would like to precalculate `mymodulus` for `n` values of `0..64` at compile time. The reason is that `mymodulus` would be really expensive and will be reused multiple times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.1/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html). With TH you can generate code programmatically, at compile time. Your mymodulus is effectively a "template" in this case.

For example, we can rewrite your program as follows, to compute your function statically. first, the main code as usual, but instead of calling your modulus function, it calls a function whose body is a splice that will be generated at compile time:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Table

mymodulus n = $(genmodulus 64)

main = mapM_ (print . mymodulus) [0..64]
```

And the code to generate the table statically:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Table where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

genmodulus :: Int -> Q Exp
genmodulus n = return $ CaseE (VarE (mkName "n"))
                              [ Match (LitP (IntegerL i))
                                      (NormalB (LitE (IntegerL (i `mod` base))))
                                      []
                              | i <- [0..fromIntegral n] ]
    where
        base = 10
```

This describes the abstract syntax of the case expression, which will be generated at compile time. We simply generate a big switch:

```
    genmodulus 64
  ======>
    case n of {
      0 -> 0
      1 -> 1
      2 -> 2
      3 -> 3
      4 -> 4
      ...
      64 -> 4 }
```

You can see what code is generated with -ddump-splices. I've written the template code in direct style. Someone more familiar with TH should be able to make the pattern code simpler.

Another option would be to generate a table of values offline, and just import that data structure.

You might also say why you wish to do this. I assume you have a very complex table-driven function?

Comment: I've got a table of `[Integer -> Integer]`. Basically that, given a value, generates a new list of values that have been made using that function from that list. I can construct those function lists automatically. Each list in the table can contain any number of functions. Basically based on a `mod` operation it chooses a list to use. But that means I can already construct them at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any way to precompile it down to a table lookup (though you may have some luck with TH). An alternative is to generate an a lookup table at runtime with something like

```
mymodulus' x = lt ! x
    where lt = array (0, 64) [(i, mymodulus i) | i <- [0..64]]
```

Comment: I think, lookup table would be basically same as just calling the function. Haskell stores called functions and their return values.

Comment: There is definitely a difference between this and an ordinary function.  It is a common misconception that Haskell memoizes all functions.  See eg. data-memocombinators on Hackage for ways to tell Haskell to memoize.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember there is some special behaviour attached to top-level definitions.
If you'll try simple example:

```
primes = 2 : 3 : filter isPrime [5, 7 .. 1000000]
isPrime x = walk (tail primes) where
    walk (y:ys) | (y*y > x) = True
                | (x `mod` y) /= 0 = walk ys
    walk _ = False
main = do
    print $ last primes
    print . last $ init primes
```

You'll see that first call of (last primes) will initiate calculation of primes and second line will reuse those calculations.